# React array returns undefined when i try to get specific element of it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I tried to do 2 data fetches, one to fetch all the products and after that is finished i map all the products and fetch each one of them separately and put them into array. The behaviour that i don't understand occurs when i try to print the results. If i console.log the whole array, everything works fine, but if i try to do it with single array item it returns undefined. Don't ask why i need to fetch all the products separately.

Here's the code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const Stackoverflow1 = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [singleData, setSingleData] = useState("");
  const [finished, setFinished] = useState(false);
  const API = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/products`;
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      axios.get(API).then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
        setFinished(true);
      });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (finished) {
      let list = [];

      data &&
        data.map(async (item) => {
          const API = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/products/${item.id}`;
          axios.get(API).then((response) => {
            list.push(response.data);
          });
        });
      setSingleData(list);
    }
  }, [finished, data]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        singleData &&
        data.map((item, index) => (
          <div>
            {item.name}
            {console.log("inside code without index", singleData)}
            {console.log("inside code with index", singleData[0])}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

//Console logs:

// inside html without index :
// []
// 0: {id: 381, name: 'Akvariumas 30l', description: 'Akvariumas 30l', price: 25.99, image_name: '16491014443.aquael-glossy-100-juodas.jpeg', …}
// 1: {id: 391, name: 'Akvariumas 20l', description: 'akvariumas 20l', price: 12, image_name: '16491031283.aquarium3.jpeg', …}
// 2: {id: 401, name: 'Akvariumas 30l', description: 'Akvariumas 30l', price: 150, image_name: '16491063713.aquarium4.jpeg', …}
// length: 3
// [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

//inside html with index undefined
```

Comment: The output does not seem to make very much sense, is there any chance you could get a screenshot of the console outputs please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Promise.all to wait all the promises:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (finished && data) {
      let list = [];
      Promise.all(data.map(async (item) => {
        const API = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/products/${item.id}`;
        const response = await axios.get(API);
        list.push(response.data)
      })).then(() => setSingleData(list))
    }
  }, [finished, data]);
```

Comment: Waiting for all the promises fixed the issue but i still don't understand why I could print the whole array but printing single array item resulted in undefined value.